# Decode hex string encoding

Tags: character-encoding, vb6

I have a .bin saved with a VB program, the .bin format is:

```
String bytes | String
06 00        | C0 E1 E0 E8 F1 E0
```

The problem is I don't know how the string is encoded. I know what the string is supposed to be: `Abaira`

Can anyone recognize the encoding used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard character encoding for this. It is neither ASCII nor EBCDIC.

It seems to be some trivial sort of 8-bit (non-Unicode) ASCII (perhaps ANSI) encryption. Compare your unknown encoding with ASCII:

```
  Unknown        ASCII
  Hex MSB  LSB   Hex MSB  LSB
A CO  1100 0000  41  0100 0001 
b E1  1110 0001  62  0110 0010
a E0  1110 0000  61  0110 0001
i E8  1110 1000  69  0110 1001
r F1  1111 0001  72  0111 0010
a E0  1110 0000  61  0110 0001
```

Let's define:

- MSB: First nibble = most significant 4 bits
- LSB: Second nibble = least significant 4 bits
- _U: of Unknown
- _A: of ASCII

Then you find:

- MSB_U = MSB_A Xor 0x80 (maybe MSB_A Or 0x80)
- LSB_U = LSB_A + 1 (to tell how overflow is handled I need to see ASCII char 'O' or 'o')
- Then U is the concatenation MSB_U & LSB_U.

Further example ASCII to Unknown:

```
ASCII Hex MSB  LSB   MSB Xor 0x80  LSB - 1  Concatenated Hex
H     48  0100 1000  1100          1001     1100 0111    C7
e     65  0110 1001  1110          1010     1110 1000    E8
r     72  0111 0010  1111          0011     1111 0001    F1 (as you have shown)
b     62  0110 0010  1110          0011     1110 0001    E1 (do.)
```

Comment: What worked for me was:

    if char <= 127 {
        char = char + 127
    } else {
        char = char -127
    }

Kinda like your Xor 0x80